# docker-node: Running as non-root user, file permissions

Tags: node.js, docker, permissions, chown

Following docker-node’s [best practices](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#non-root-user), I want to run my node app as non-root user. The recommendation is as follows:

```
FROM node:6.10.3
...
# At the end, set the user to use when running this image
USER node
```

My simplified Dockerfile currently looks like this:

```
FROM node:6.10.3
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

So, all the files added during image build are owned by `root`, but `node server.js` is run as the `node` user. This seems to work fine.

**My question:** Is there any additional security benefit from `chown`-ing the files so that they belong to `node` instead of `root`? I.e. doing something like:

```
RUN chown -R node:node .
```

Comment: Pretty sure that would actually decrease security as someone who can hijack your process could alter the files if they belonged to node.

Comment: @JohannesMerz Very reasonable point, which I hadn't even thought about!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It definitely does, however I would also remove the `chown` binary (as well as all admin tools). This would make it harder when someone accesses the container as e.g. root. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29584184/3580261) for a related answer.

Also, see [this](https://github.com/microversecloud/docker-alpine-hardened/blob/master/harden.sh) `Dockerfile` for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll have a closer look at the links tomorrow!