# How to map user permissions defined in a Docker container that already exist on the host

Tags: postgresql, docker, permissions, dockerfile

I want to run postgres inside a Docker container with a mounted volume. I am following steps as describe [here](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2017/06/14/running-postgresql-in-docker/). However, the container never starts. I think this is because the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory is owned by user `postgres` with `uid 999`, and group `postgres` with `gid 999`.

My understanding is that I need to create a user and group with the same `uid` and `gid` on my host (the name doesn't matter), and assign these permissions to the directory I am mounting on my host.

The problem is that the `uid` and `gid` are already taken on my host. I can rebuild the Docker image from the Dockerfile and modify the `uid` and `gid` values, but I don't think this is a good long term solution as I want to be able to use the official postgres images from Docker Hub.

My question is, if a container defines permissions that already exist on the host, how do you map permission from the host to the container without having to rebuild the container itself with the configuration from your environment?

If I am misunderstanding things or am way off the mark, what is the right way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are right about `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. When you run the container it changes, in the container, the owner of the files in that directory to user `postgres` (with user id 999). If the files are already present in the mounted volume, changing the ownership may fail if the user you run docker with does not have the right permissions. There is an excellent explanation about file ownership in docker here [Understanding user file ownership in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500270/understanding-user-file-ownership-in-docker-how-to-avoid-changing-permissions-o).

> My question is, if a container defines permissions that already exist on the host, how do you map permission from the host to the container without having to rebuild the container itself with the configuration from your environment?

I think what you might be looking for is docker user namespaces. [Introduction to User Namespaces in Docker Engine](https://success.docker.com/article/introduction-to-user-namespaces-in-docker-engine). It allows you to fix permissions in docker volumes.

For your specific case if don't want the files in the mounted volume to have `uid` 999 you could just override the entrypoint of the container and change the `uid` of the user `postgres`.

```
docker run --entrypoint="bash" postgres -c  'usermod -u 2006 postgres;exec /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres'
```