# How to set access right on docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is a simple dummy docker-compose :

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  webserver:
    image: "webserver:latest" // apache, nginx, caddy, whatever
  volumes:
    - "shared_storage:/app/storage/shared"

  analyser:
    image: "custom:latest" // any custom script doing stuff on a volume
  volumes:
    - "shared_storage:/local/storage/shared"

volumes:
  shared_storage
```

The problem is, the `shared_storage` is mounted as own by `root` with rights `644` (or any user I can set using `user:`) but the webserver is internally running as `www-data` user (whose I cannot know the id in advance).
How can I grant the webserver the access to the `shared_storage`  volume ?

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding user file ownership in docker: how to avoid changing permissions of linked volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500270/understanding-user-file-ownership-in-docker-how-to-avoid-changing-permissions-o)

Comment: Ok, I read those resources and endedup with a solution. Ty vm Dorin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I read dorin's resources and ended up with this working file:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  grant:
    image: "webserver:latest" // apache, nginx, caddy, whatever
    volumes:
      - "shared_storage:/app/storage/shared"
    entrypoint: "bin/chown"
    command: ["www-data:www-data", "/app/storage/shared"]
  
  webserver:
    image: "webserver:latest" // apache, nginx, caddy, whatever
    depends_on: grant
    volumes:
      - "shared_storage:/app/storage/shared"

  analyser:
    image: "custom:latest" // any custom script doing stuff on a volume
    volumes:
      - "shared_storage:/local/storage/shared"

volumes:
  shared_storage
```